# PHP: Check if string contains characters NOT in array

Tags: php

I want to validate that a string consists of numbers or commas or semicolons:

valid: `1.234`
valid: `1,234`
invalid: `1.23a`
invalid: `1.2_4`

What works:

use `str_split` to create an array out of the string and use `in_array` with `array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,',',';')`.

But this feels circuitous to me and since I have to do this with millions of strings I want to make sure there is no more efficient way.

Question: Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Inverting the character class / allowed characters and negating the return of `preg_match()` is likely to perform better than matching the whole string.  In other words, stop searching the string as soon as a character that is not in your white list is found in the string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only need to validate a string (not sanitize or modify it), you can use regex. Try the following:

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9\,\;\.]+$/', $string)) {
     // ok
} else {
    // not ok
}
```

Comment: this approach will return `false`("not ok") for the input `1.234`. While the OP expects it to be valid: *valid: 1.234 valid: 1,234 invalid: 1.23a invalid: 1.2_4*

Comment: @Nitin I think, he intended float numbers ... I suppose

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest you are right. I only realized that after going through the question again. But, there was no dot in the array either.

Answer (score 2):

The solution using `preg_match` function:

```
// using regexp for (numbers OR commas OR semicolons) - as you've required
function isValid($str) {
    return (bool) preg_match("/^([0-9.]|,|;)+$/", $str);
}

var_dump(isValid("1.234"));  // bool(true)
var_dump(isValid("1.23a"));  // bool(false)
var_dump(isValid("1,234"));  // bool(true)
```